# Detect Objects on a table

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection

is it possible to train a model which detects and draws bounding boxes for objects on a table, when I use a dataset where objects on a table are labeled with boundingboxes?

Comment: Yes, surely it can be done. Checkout the papers of models like: Yolo and R-CNN

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Provided the dataset contains the objects that you actually want your model to detect during run time.